# Change IMAP folder subscriptions on default email client

Tags: email, imap, stock-email-app

I've set up an IMAP account in the default email client (android 2.2.1), and have added and removed some folders on the IMAP folder. How do I change the android email settings to subscribe to these new folders?

Answer (score 1):

### Email APP

If you are referring to the APP named "Email", you don't have to make any adjustments, the subscription process is fully automated, I just test.

**Ps:** No options available on this application for that type of settings, perhaps the reason as to why its fully automated and by default in sync.

---

### Gmail APP

If you are referring to the Gmail APP, you need to:

1. Open the APP
2. Tap your device "menu"
3. Tap "more", then "settings"
4. Tap your account
5. Scroll down until you find "Sync inboxes and labels", and tap
6. A list should appear with all your folders, tap over the ones you need to Sync and select the desirable option.